# How do I implement yolov5 to a ros2 subscriber node?

Tags: ros, yolov5, ros2

I want to implement a yolov5 algorithm to a `ROS2` subscriber. But it claims that yolov5 not found.

```bash
$ ros2 run yolov5_detect webcam_yolo_sub 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jun/ros2_guyue/colcon_ws/install/yolov5_detect/lib/yolov5_detect/webcam_yolo_sub", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('yolov5-detect==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'webcam_yolo_sub')())
  File "/home/jun/ros2_guyue/colcon_ws/install/yolov5_detect/lib/yolov5_detect/webcam_yolo_sub", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jun/ros2_guyue/colcon_ws/install/yolov5_detect/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yolov5_detect/webcam_yolo_sub.py", line 12, in <module>
    from yolov5 import detect_ros
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov5'
```

I have rewritten the `detector` as a class and have successfully launched in ROS1 noetic.
Basing on the error message above, I think it maybe because for ROS1 the .py script is exactly the executable file of `$ rosrun <pkg_name> <node_name>`, while for ROS2 the file to be run is generated in `/workspace/install`, therefore the yolov5 folder cannot link to the executable file correctly.
My question is: **how to implement an algorithm from outside in ROS2 framework?**
Click to [check my code on github](https://github.com/junmeng6025/ros2_yolov5)
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look a [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/367793/including-a-python-module-in-a-ros2-package/) in the ROS forum. This will solve your problem.

ROS related questions are more likely to be answered there.

Comment: That's exactly the problem I've met. Thank you very much!